# Set the HTML by calling using its ID or Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of menus like

```
<ul id="toc">
 <li><a href="#description35116" class="job_content">Description</a></li>
 <li><a href="#msg_body35116" class="job_content">Messages</a></li>
 <li><a class="job_content">Applicants</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then i have a div like

```
<div id="job_item35116" class="items">

</div>
```

Then i have some more divs like

```
<div id="#description35116">

</div>

<div id="#msg_body35116">

</div>
```

So i am trying to do is when i will click the list item then these div (#description35116) will be appended inside `id="job_item35116"`. (One item at a time)

So can i append a div with its `ID` inside another div ??

I tried like

JS (But its not working)

```
$('.job_content').unbind('click').click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var job_item = '#job_item'+ id;
    if($(job_item).children().length > 0 ){
        $(".items").empty();
        $(href).toggle();   
    }else{
        $(href).toggle();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. I see `id="35116"` used twice. Also a suggestion don't use meta-characters in IDs as `id="#msg_body35116"`

Comment: Okay i edited...the actual problem is can we append a div in to another by using the ID

Comment: `$('#job_item35116').append($('#\\#description35116'))` or `$('#\\#description35116').appendTo($('#job_item35116'))`

Comment: Yes, it's just a matter of parsing the ID No out in JS/JQ and the appending a div an applying the same reference to it as an ID.

Comment: @Satpal ID already unique....35116 is just number after some different text.No need to change this

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper, You are reading question after OP has edited it.

Comment: @Satpal As i can see  This question is not edited.otherwise there should be icon of edited....?? or i can't see edited questions??explain

Comment: @Mr7-itsurdeveloper, Ninja-edits(If you with-in 5 mins of posting they are not recorded) Read OPs comment __Okay i edited...the actual problem is can we append a div in to another by using the ID__ I thinks that good for you

Comment: @Satpal Okay i gone through your answer but i didn't find any clue...any other suggestion

Comment: Instead of `$(href)` use `$("#\\" + href)` to escape meta-character `#`

Comment: @Satpal No the problem lies in removing the children i think so, bcoz $(href).toggle is working...thought i need one div at a time..need to remove the chidren of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/aT7pF/1/**

1. Remove the "#" from you ID-names in the div. It makes you live more easy.
2. From a coder perspective: Just place blank text within the `</li>`-tags. you don't need a `<a href/>`. Instead add a custom attribute to your  tags, eg **divId** which you use to store the value of the `</div>`. it makes more sense this way. With JQuery you can fetch the value which you stored in your custom attribute easily with `.attr()`

(Refactored) HTML:

```
<ul id="toc">
    <li divId="description35116">Description</li>
    <li divId="msg_body35116">Messages</li>
    <li>Applicants
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="job_item35116" class="items"></div>
<div id="description35116">description35116</div>
<div id="msg_body35116">msg_body35116</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#description35116").hide();
$("#msg_body35116").hide();


var divId = $(this).attr("divId");
/* 
you can make this line shorter:
$("#job_item35116").empty().append("<div>" +$("#"+divId).html() + "<div>");
*/

// by doing this:
$("#job_item35116").html("<div>" +$("#"+divId).html() + "<div>");
```

Comment: just use `.empty()` before you use `.append()`. update JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/aT7pF/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/aT7pF/2/)

Comment: yes i tried before u said....but not working ...i will edit my question what i tried...

Comment: ? What you mean? The new JSFiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/aT7pF/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/aT7pF/2/) works. It shows you the content, one at the time of each `<div/>` wihtin the `<div id="job_item35116"/>`. I Also edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#toc li').on('click','a',function(e){
 e.preventDefault(); 
 var id = $(this).attr('href');
 var div = $('<div id="' + id + '"></div>');
  $(div).text(id);
 $('.items').append($(div));

});
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YHFuV/)**

Comment: @RIADev Yes you can but with slight modifications. Check this ***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHFuV/1/)***